# How to make cell empty in tabulator once user click on it?

Tags: javascript, tabulator

I want to make the cell empty once the user clicks on the cell or user jumps on it by pressing the tab key.

Is there any way to do it? I am using tabulator 4.7.2

I have tried cell.setValue("") but it is giving below error

```
Uncaught DOMException: Failed to set the 'innerHTML' property on 'Element': The node to be removed is no longer a child of this node. Perhaps it was moved in a 'blur' event handler?
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure where you were trying to call `cell.setValue()` but after a cursory look at their documentation it looks like a simple place to start is to implement their table wide callbacks [Tabulator: Callbacks](http://tabulator.info/docs/4.1/callbacks#cell).

Here is a minimal example based on their quick start example table. It implements three callbacks: `cellEditing`, `cellEditingCancelled` and `cellEdited`. `cellEditing` is called when an editable cell gains focus. I've used it to store the current value so that it can be restored if the user cancels editing. `cellEditingCancelled` restores the old value in case of the above. `cellEdited` is not utilized here, but fires after an edit is finished and provides access to the final edited value. (In this example it will fire after we set the cell value to `""` and again when the cell is exited, either with the newly edited value, or the restored value from `cellEditingCancelled`)

```js
var tabledata = [
    {id:1, name:"Oli Bob", age:"12", col:"red", dob:""},
    {id:2, name:"Mary May", age:"1", col:"blue", dob:"14/05/1982"},
    {id:3, name:"Christine Lobowski", age:"42", col:"green", dob:"22/05/1982"},
    {id:4, name:"Brendon Philips", age:"125", col:"orange", dob:"01/08/1980"},
    {id:5, name:"Margret Marmajuke", age:"16", col:"yellow", dob:"31/01/1999"},
 ];
 
let oldValue;
//create Tabulator on DOM element with id "example-table"
var table = new Tabulator("#example-table", {
   cellEditing:function(cell){
    //e - the click event object
    //cell - cell component
    oldValue = cell.getValue();
    cell.setValue("", true);
   },
   cellEditCancelled:function(cell){
    //cell - cell component
    cell.setValue(oldValue, true);
    oldValue = "";
   },
   cellEdited:function(cell){
    //cell - cell component
   },
    height:205, // set height of table (in CSS or here), this enables the Virtual DOM and improves render speed dramatically (can be any valid css height value)
    data:tabledata, //assign data to table
    layout:"fitColumns", //fit columns to width of table (optional)
    columns:[ //Define Table Columns
        {title:"Name", field:"name", editor:"input", width:150},
        {title:"Age", field:"age", editor:"number", hozAlign:"left", formatter:"progress"},
        {title:"Favourite Color", editor:"input", field:"col"},
        {title:"Date Of Birth", editor:"input", field:"dob", sorter:"date", hozAlign:"center"},
    ],
    
});
```

```html
<link href="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.7.2/dist/css/tabulator.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://unpkg.com/tabulator-tables@4.7.2/dist/js/tabulator.min.js"></script>
<div id="example-table"></div>
```

Comment: `cellEditing` is the thing I needed. Not sure how I missed this. Thanks!